# How do i interrupt a thread from another thread in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm writing a simple program.
A thread will run infinitely printing, say counting :

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
private int count = 0;
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        System.out.println(count++);

        try { currentThread().sleep(2000); }
        catch (InterruptedException ignored) { }
    }
  }
}
```

until user gives any (String) input of more than 2 letters :

```
class MyThreadStopper extends Thread {
       MyThread obj ;
       MyThreadStopper(MyThread obj) {
           this.obj = obj;
       }
     public void run() {
        String userInput ;
        while(true) {
            userInput = (new Scanner(System.in)).next();

            if( userInput.length() > 2) {
                obj.interrupt();
                currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            try{ currentThread().sleep(1000); }
            catch (InterruptedException ignored) { } 
        }
     }
  }
```

Used one thread for printing and another thread of different class to get input. I'm not sure where i am doing it wrong.

```
class temp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThread obj = new MyThread();
        MyThreadStopper objStop = new MyThreadStopper(obj);
        obj.start();
        objStop.start();
    }
}
```

As it keeps printing infinitely, even though i tried printing the `userInput` and removing `if` after the `userInput`.

Answer (score 1):

you are ignoring the interrupt:
you could stop the thread when it is interrupted (or do something else, depeding on the requirements)

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
private int count = 0;
public void run() {
    while(!interrupted) {
        System.out.println(count++);

        try { currentThread().sleep(2000); }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // we got interrupted, time to do something
            interrupted = true;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

generally interrupting a thread to stop it is rarely a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
private int count = 0;
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        System.out.println(count++);

        try { currentThread().sleep(2000); }
        catch (InterruptedException ignored) { 
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
            break;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

You were not doing anything once you are catching InterruptedException. So loop was continuing. The above modified code should print "Interrupted" & break.

Comment: some advice: ```try { currentThread().sleep(2000); }
        catch (InterruptedException ignored) { 
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // keep the interrupt status
            break;
        }```